# Resizing a .tiff file for print on 3M x 4M canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resize, resolution

I have a .tiff file of an image, it is 17815 x 12426 px and is landscape. I need to print it 3 x 4 metres portrait, it's for a wall vinyl or canvas. The resolution is 500dpi. So if I try to resize it at 300x400 cm it isn't high enough to do so without stretching it bigger.

Would it be best to do it at half size eg. 150 x 200 cm then tell the printer to output at 200% or what would be the best solution? also should the resolution stay at 500dpi?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For artwork this simple you don't really need to do anything at all apart from crop the image so it fits a 4:3 ratio format, and then tell the printer what the finished size should be.

The image data doesn't really have an intrinsic resolution. You say it's 500dpi, but all that means is that it's nominally set up to print at that output resolution - which would give you a 35.6" x 24.8" print.

The image is proportionally too wide, so you'll need to crop left and/or right edges.

You'll end up with an 16568 px x 12426 px image.

When printed at 4m x 3m, output resolution will be (16568 / 4) = (12426 / 4) ~= 41 px/cm ~= 105 ppi.

Resampling the image should not be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would do.

Create a new document in InDesign of the size of the final product you are going to have printed (3x4m).

Place the image that you have in its original "RAW" format into InDesign and adjust it (add crop marks, adjust centering, text, anything else you might want...).

When this is done, create a new A4-sized document and copy and paste your photo from document 1 into it. Print it on your home or office computer.

This will give you a very precise idea of what one single detail of this image file will result in when printed, at the size you need. If it's pixelated, try to get a higher resolution version or use fractal image resizing software. If it looks good, export the InDesign file to PDF for print and send it to the printers.